# How to pyplot pause() for zero time?

Tags: animation, matplotlib, draw, show, pause

I'm plotting an animation of circles. It looks and works great as long as `speed` is set to a positive number. However, I want to set `speed` to `0.0`. When I do that, something changes and it no longer animates. Instead, I have to click the 'x' on the window after each frame. I tried using combinations of `plt.draw()` and `plt.show()` to get the same effect as `plt.pause()`, but the frames don't show up. How do I replicate the functionality of `plt.pause()` precisely either without the timer involved or with it set to `0.0`?

```
speed = 0.0001
plt.ion()
for i in range(timesteps):
    fig, ax = plt.subplots()
    for j in range(num):
        circle = plt.Circle(a[j], b[j]), r[j], color='b')
        fig.gca().add_artist(circle)
    plt.pause(speed)
    #plt.draw()
    #plt.show()
    plt.clf()
    plt.close()
```

Answer (score 4):

I've copied the code of `pyplot.pause()` here:

```
def pause(interval):
    """
    Pause for *interval* seconds.

    If there is an active figure it will be updated and displayed,
    and the GUI event loop will run during the pause.

    If there is no active figure, or if a non-interactive backend
    is in use, this executes time.sleep(interval).

    This can be used for crude animation. For more complex
    animation, see :mod:`matplotlib.animation`.

    This function is experimental; its behavior may be changed
    or extended in a future release.

    """
    backend = rcParams['backend']
    if backend in _interactive_bk:
        figManager = _pylab_helpers.Gcf.get_active()
        if figManager is not None:
            canvas = figManager.canvas
            canvas.draw()
            show(block=False)
            canvas.start_event_loop(interval)
            return

    # No on-screen figure is active, so sleep() is all we need.
    import time
    time.sleep(interval)
```

As you can see, it calls [start_event_loop](http://matplotlib.org/api/backend_bases_api.html?highlight=start_event_loop#matplotlib.backend_bases.FigureCanvasBase.start_event_loop), which starts a separate crude event loop for `interval` seconds. What happens if `interval` == 0 seems backend-dependend. For instance, for the WX backend a value of 0 means that this loop is blocking and never ends (I had to look in [the code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/v1.5.0/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_wx.py) here, it doesn't show up in the documentation. See line 773).

In short, 0 is a special case. Can't you set it to a small value, e.g. 0.1 seconds?

The `pause` docstring above says that it can only be used for crude anmiations, you may have to resort to the [animation module](http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html#module-matplotlib.animation) if you want something more sophisticated.